# How to add a custom field to existing entity in MedusaJS

Tags: typescript, postgresql, entity, typeorm, medusajs

I would like to add a custom field(named **description**) to **ProductCollection** Entity in MedusaJS server application. What I have followed so far is that:

- created a new file under `src/models` folder, which is `myCollection.ts` with following content

```
import { Column, Entity } from "typeorm";
import { ProductCollection } from "@medusajs/medusa";

@Entity()
export class MyProductCollection extends ProductCollection {
  @Column({ type: "varchar" })
  description: string | null;
}
```

- created an migration using this command: `npx typeorm migration:create -n DescriptionAdded --dir src/migrations` and it gives me new file under folder `src/migrations` named `1674744755671-DescriptionAdded.ts` and I edited the file like this:

```
import { MigrationInterface, QueryRunner, TableColumn } from "typeorm";

export class DescriptionAdded1674744755671 implements MigrationInterface {
  public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
    await queryRunner.addColumn(
      "product_collection",
      new TableColumn({
        name: "description",
        type: "varchar",
        isNullable: true,
      })
    );
  }

  public async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
    await queryRunner.dropColumn("product_collection", "description");
  }
}
```

Then I run the migration using this command `medusa migrations run`. And as I expected, it created the field in database table. Then I built the medusa application by this command `yarn run build`. And I restarted the application with `yarn run start`. I am using latest medusajs server application with the latest medusa package which is **1.7.5**.

What I expected is that getting this field when I call the following api:

`http://localhost:9000/store/collections`

I have created the medusajs server app with these commands:

```
yarn global add @medusajs/medusa-cli
medusa new my-medusa-store --seed
```

I am running medusa server app on my local and it does not give the new field named **description**.

I could not find how to add custom field to medusa server application. What is the way of extending existing entities in medusajs server application? I have seen **[medusa-extender](https://adrien2p.github.io/medusa-extender/#/)** repository but it does not show any example how to do it.

I hope you might help me.

Thanks

I have installed medusa server app using medusa/cli and added files described above. I could not find any documentation about this on [medusajs](https://medusajs.com/) website.

Answer (score 5):

Co-author of Medusa here.

We generally advise developers to not extend the core database schemas with additional columns, as it could compromise the maintainability of your setup. Therefore, we do not expose a native way to do it. Though, we have plans to add a Custom Field API in the near future, that would effectively allow you to extend your schemas, but not directly. It will likely be accomplished following an EAV pattern.

Also, it seems you might have confused new entities with additional table columns. When you add models in `/src/models`, you add new **tables** to your database - not columns. Read more [here](https://docs.medusajs.com/advanced/backend/entities/).

I do not have experience with Typeorm's `addColumn` functionality, so I can't say anything about how that affects your setup. What I can say is that we query a set of default fields and relations on entities in most `GET /store/*` endpoints. If you don't explicitly provide your additional fields, they will not be part of the response.

Regarding the extender, you can indeed use that to extend your database schemas but, again, it comes with the caveat of potentially compromising the maintainability of your instance and future upgrade paths.